# SendTextMessage doesn't send SMS

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I'm not getting any errors, but I don't see any SMS received on my phone either. My code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
        )
    ) {
        // User has denied
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            Array<String?>(10) { Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS

        )
    }
} else {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("TAG", "SENDING SMS!")
        val number = "1234567890"
        val message = "Verification message."
        val sm: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null)
    }
}
```

I do get the "SENDING SMS" logged in my console, so it means everything is ok regarding permissions, yet no SMS is being sent.

What could be the reason of the SMS not being sent?

P.S I'm using this random phone number "12345..", does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid, I thought the number should be the sender's number and it's just for displaying it, it has to be the receiver's number of course.